# How do I create a lift curve?

Tags: logistic, modeling, model-selection, model-comparison

I am having trouble constructing a lift curve from scratch.

Say I have bunch of 0-1 labels, and predictive labels. In order to construct the lift curve, I do the following steps (assume I have already trained my model using a logistic regression):

1. make a prediction using the validation set
2. Sort the outcome of step #1 in terms of decreasing probability (here, I am talking about the probability of getting a label 1)
3. Then,  I divide this sorted outcomes into 10 bin of equal size.
4. For each bin, I do the following:

   i) Count the number of true- label 1 occurrences.

   ii) Do a random samples (say n = 200), and count the number of true-label 1 occurrences in the random samples

   iii) divide step-i) by step-ii) to get the lift.
5. Repeat this for the remaining bins.

Is this the correct way to build a lift curve from scratch?